# Get same day of week last year Excel formula

Tags: date, excel-formula

Would it be possible to get same day of week last year using Excel? please below example:

Input: Monday 9 Nov 2015 | Output: 10 Nov 2014

Thanks

Comment: You meant 10 Nov 2014?

Comment: Got a question: If input date is Thursday 31 Dec 2015 what is your expected output?

Answer (score 7):

Simply subtract 52 full weeks with 7 days = 364 days. So if the date is in `A1`, the formula `=A1-364` will get the date exactly 52 weeks before, which is the same day of week in the year before.

To show that it works even for leap years, try the following:

[image]
[image]

You see the formula `date - 364` (`=A2-364, =A3-364`, ...) always gets the same day of week a year before. That is because it gets the day minus 52 full weeks (52 * 7 days) before. In leap years it gets a different day but the same day of week.

Comment: If for any number years back, my formula should be the choice, right? No offence. Thank you.

Comment: This is great! A simple solution which always works.

Comment: won't this break on a leap year?

Comment: @DennisP: No, it will not. See my supplement in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

=DATE(YEAR(A1)-1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))+WEEKDAY(A1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1)-1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)))

It returns the closest date within a week. A1 is the cell with this year's date.